# LEFT JOIN no me devuelve los nulos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, join

La idea es un blog que tiene sus categorías, lo que quiero es que me muestre las que mas entradas tengan, pero también que me devuelva las categorías que no tengan entradas. Lo estoy haciendo con un left join pero no me muestra todas las nulas, solo una. Aca el codigo de las tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE categorias(
id      int(255) auto_increment not null,
nombre  varchar(100) not null,

CONSTRAINT pk_categorias PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE= InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE entradas(
id                  int(255) auto_increment not null,
usuario_id          int(255) not null,
categoria_id        int(255) not null,
titulo              varchar(255) not null,
descripcion         MEDIUMTEXT,
fecha               date not null,

CONSTRAINT pk_entradas PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_entrada_usuario FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_entrada_categoria FOREIGN KEY(categoria_id) REFERENCES categorias(id) ON #DELETE# #UPDATE#  CASCADE
)ENGINE= InnoDb;
```

Y aca la consulta que estoy haciendo:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(e.id) AS 'num_entradas' FROM entradas e
RIGHT JOIN categorias c ON c.id = e.categoria_id
GROUP BY e.categoria_id ORDER BY COUNT(e.id) DESC;
```

Me devuelve solo 5 que son los que tienen entradas y uno que no tiene pero igualmente me lo devuelve. Otros 3 que no tienen entra

Comment: Su consulta parece una opción correcta, lo único que necesita es agrupar por `c.id` y no por `e.categoria_id`, además cambie `c.*` por `c.id` y debería obtener el resultado que necesita.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que te devuelva todas las entradas, tengan o no categoría, puedes hacer un left join de la siguiente forma:

```html
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  entradas e LEFT JOIN categorias c ON e.categoria_id = c.id
WHERE
  e.categoria_id IS NULL
```

Con esta consulta veras todas las entradas, las que tengan la columna categoria_id a nulo serán las que no tienen categoría asignada.